# How to set foreground (text) color in xcolor table?

Tags: tables, color

How do I pick the foreground (text) color in `xcolor` table for the whole row?  such that the letters appear white with blue background in this table (instead of black which is bad for constrast):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \rowcolor{blue}%\textcolor{white}
    10 & 20 & 30 \\
    11 & 21 & 31 \\
    12 & 22 & 32 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: blackonblueisbad]

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, thanks for the pointer, is it possible to make it work without using another package (`tabu`)? Also I couldn't make `rowcolor` and `rowfont` work at the same time.

Comment: you need to use `\rowfont` first: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabu}{lll}
    \rowfont{\color{white}}\rowcolor{blue}
    10 & 20 & 30 \    11 & 21 & 31 \    12 & 22 & 32 \    \end{tabu}
\end{document}`. For a solution without `tabu`, let me see if I can find a link to an answer by David Carlisle.

Comment: Yep. Here's the link to David's answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62466/3954 you can adapt it to use standard `l` columns instead of `X` columns.